# Gantt Chart in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, mobile, gantt-chart

I need to implement Gantt chart similar to this https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/timeline/custom.xhtml , but it seems there is no such chart in charts_flutter or any other similar library.
I been looking for something similar in an any popular chart library but no luck :(

Comment: Have managed to solve your problem? I have a similar requirement..

Comment: nope, I am working on my own solution. If You interested, I create repo and we can work together on problem

Comment: sure thing, I`m interested

Comment: sorry, this is not my task anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Check the links..

```
class GanttChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController animationController;
  final DateTime fromDate;
  final DateTime toDate;
  final List<Project> data;
  final List<User> usersInChart;

  int viewRange;
  int viewRangeToFitScreen = 6;
  Animation<double> width;

  GanttChart({
    this.animationController,
    this.fromDate,
    this.toDate,
    this.data,
    this.usersInChart,
  }) {
    viewRange = calculateNumberOfMonthsBetween(fromDate, toDate);
  }
```

[Github Link](https://github.com/beesightsoft/bss_flutter_open/blob/master/lib/calendar_demo/gantt_chart/gantt_chart_screen.dart)

[Medium article](https://medium.com/@phungnlg/gantt-chart-with-flutter-d754f941bbe4)