# Create a gantt chart in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, package, gantt-chart

I wanted to add a Gantt chart in my flutter application based on the start and end date of any events from the google calendar. But I did not find any articles or packages which can help me to create a Gantt chart.
Is there any way or references I can look at to create a Gantt chart in my application?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265280/gantt-chart-in-flutter-dart).

I have been trying to implement something like this for a while now, and found the resources below useful.

[A Medium article](https://medium.com/@phungnlg/gantt-chart-with-flutter-d754f941bbe4)

[A Github repo](https://github.com/beesightsoft/bss_flutter_open/blob/master/lib/calendar_demo/gantt_chart/gantt_chart_screen.dart)